# How to trigger this completion in ipython?

Tags: ipython

The usual completion using tab works fine for me. However, it seems that sometimes, ipython shows a candidate completion on typing:

[image]

What kind of completion is this? It seems to differ from history completion. And, most importantly, how do I trigger this completion? Neither tab nor ^P works: tab completes something else, and ^P Does not work in multiline commands.